# How to display Image in Div using Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

This code is working fine To display Image in Img Tag

```
$scope.isImage = function(ext) {
  if(ext) {
    return ext == "jpg" || ext == "jpeg"|| ext == "gif" || ext=="png"
  }
}
```

Here is working demo http://plnkr.co/edit/rAZVSFRURCkgxQrZAtvO?p=preview

I would like to display Image in

```
<div style="background-image:url(How can i get browsed image file)"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a path string in DOM to represent your browsed file and then add it as background image url. I got it working by modifying your code like below.

```
<body>
    <form action="" id="contactproForm" method="post" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label for="file">Attachment</label>
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="file" id="file" class="input-text" ngf-change="onChange(picFile)" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="attachement" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/pdf " />
        </div>
        <div id="image"class="image" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-image:url('');"></div>       <!-- div with id="image"-->

    </form>


    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileUpload']);

    app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$compile', 'Upload',
        function($scope, $http, $timeout, $compile, Upload) {
            $scope.onChange = function(files) {
                if (files[0] == undefined) return;
                if($scope.isImage(files[0].name.split(".").pop())){  // checking if image
                    var path = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);       //  creating a path for file
                    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + path + ")";   // setting it as background image of div
                }else{
                    alert("not Image");
                }
            }

            $scope.isImage = function(ext) {
                if (ext) {
                    return ext == "jpg" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "gif" || ext == "png"
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
    </script>

</body>
```

I've added comments for changes made.

Comment: This could be improved by encapsulating the code into a custom directive

Comment: Also, since the OP is using ng-file-upload, can you use the ngf-background directive? https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: There is a issue @nijeesh. background-image doesnot work for pdf etc.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-style instead of style like this and replace image url.

ng-style="{'background-image':'url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png)'}">

Comment: This won't work for images stored on the users local machine. You need to open the file, read it's data and create a data URL like in the answer of @Nijeesh.