# How to display folder contents in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, file, directory, filereader

I am new to Angularjs and I am working on a project that one of the feature is to display the files of a specific folder.

I don't know how to do it. I already searched a lot of things but I think my knowledge is not enough to understand such things. I want to display the files inside the folder (specifically image files) and display it on a div.

Comment: What type of data you have to show?

Comment: the actual image sir

Comment: Do you want directory files from client computer ? or from server ?

Comment: Perhaps this can help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376879/how-to-display-image-in-div-using-angular-js

Comment: You can't read a folder's content from client due to security reasons. The only way to work around is to use a plugin with elevated rights, or use a local server (node etc.) which can list the content and serve the list to the client. You can however multi-select files in a folder if that helps.

Comment: This seems to be abandoned without the requested clarifications, so voting to close as "unclear" for now.